# adding a textSpacing property to actionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript, timer

I'm new to programming and I'm just trying to add a certain property to a Countdown timer script in ActionScript 2.0.

Everything look fine and is working properly, the only thing missing, is that I want to add more text spacing between the numbers (so I can add a picture (shadow like) behind each of them).

Could anybody help me pointing me on the right direction to add a TextSpacing property to my code, I'm not really familiar with the actionscript syntax:

```
this.onEnterFrame = function()
{
 var today:Date = new Date();
 var currentYear = today.getFullYear();
 var currentTime = today.getTime();
 var targetDate:Date = new Date(currentYear,8,4);
 var targetTime = targetDate.getTime();
 var timeLeft = targetTime - currentTime;
 var sec = Math.floor(timeLeft/1000);
 var min = Math.floor(sec/60);
 var hours = Math.floor(min/60);
 var days = Math.floor(hours/24);
 sec = String(sec % 60);
 if(sec.length < 2){
  sec = "0" + sec;
 }
 min = String(min % 60);
 if(min.length < 2){
  min = "0" + min;
 }
 hours = String(hours % 24);
 if(hours.length < 2){
  hours = "0" + hours;
 }
 days = String(days);
 if(timeLeft > 0 ){
  var counter:String = days + ":" + hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
  time_txt.text = counter;

 }else{
  trace("TIME'S UP");
        var newTime:String = "00:00:00:00";
        time_txt.text = newTime;
        delete (this.onEnterFrame);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// create text format
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.letterSpacing = 10;

// set text format
time_txt.setTextFormat(format);
```

For performance, I would do it outside of your onEnterFrame loop, since you only need to do it once.

More info...

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001626.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001650.html